# jQuery .on() not working with string variable as key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to use a string variable as a key in a jQuery `.on()` object.

I wrote a jsfiddle that illustrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/KHPUV/

I understand that this perhaps isn't specifically a jQuery problem and more to do with the use of a variable in general, but what would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do? (use a string variable as a key).

Click doesn't work in the following example, but `mouseover` and `mouseout` does:

```
var responseEvent = 'click';
$('#el').on({
    'mouseover'        : mouseOver,
    'mouseout'         : mouseOut,
    responseEvent      : mouseClick
 });
```

Comment: The keys of object literals are always interpreted as strings.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, but does that mean what I'm attempting isn't possible?

Comment: Don't worry, it's a valid question. Björns answer shows you how you can achieve it.

Comment: Is it a real task? In what case you need to resolve the event type in runtime?

Comment: responseEvent resolves to 'click' or 'touchstart' depending on environment for certain projects. Click event has awful delay on tablets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. However, you could create the object separately and passing it as a parameter to `.on()`;

```
var responseEvent = 'click',
    props = {
        'mouseover': mouseOver,
        'mouseout' : mouseOut
    };
props[responseEvent] = mouseClick;

$('#el').on(props);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, seems to do the job! I've updated the jsfiddle for anyone interested: http://jsfiddle.net/rUGFy/. (will mark as correct when it allows me)

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because Javascript interprets the responseEvent as a key name, not as a variable, in the object you pass to .on().
Consider this:

```
var str = 'key3';
var o1 = {
    'key1': 'value1'
    'key2': 'value2'
    str: 'value3'
};
```

Now o1.key1 == 'value1', as expected. However o1.str == 'value3', not o1.key3 == 'value3'.

If you want to you can build your events objects as follows

```
var eventObjects = {};
var responseEvent = 'click';
eventObjects[responseEvent] = function(evt){...};
eventObjects['mouseover'] = function(evt){...};
$('#el').on(eventObjects);
```

The notation with [] is another way to access properties of javascript objects, that allows for variable names.

Comment: An interesting approach! are you missing commas in your o1?